# Text is pushed under image when table column is resized in React

Tags: html, css, styled-components

**Disclaimer**: I'm a beginner CSS guy so the title might be inconvenient. If you know how to reorganize the title better, please edit it :)

I have a custom DataTable component in React which I did not code. The DataTable has a feature that enables users to resize the columns size by dragging it. One of the columns I have is a `Data type` column. At the beginning, it looked like (1) in the picture. If I resize it on the left, it looked like (2) in the picture. I can see that the element is not pushed but shorten (maybe goes under the `td` element?). I decided to add image next to the text so it looks like (3). However, when I resize it on the left, the text is pushed, rather than shorten like previously and it looks like (4).

[image: DataTable column]

I have a styled component for the image

```
const Image = styled.img`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  float: left;
`;
```

I then use this component inside my DataTable like

```
<div>
   <Image src={src} />
   <span style={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>{columnDataType}</span>
</div>
```

The `td` element in which the image with text is shown has the following style:

```
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
background-color: transparent;
```

What concerns me here is, is it possible to achieve (4) to be like (2) by keeping the picture next to the text? If so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: So you want to have text like (2) in (4) with an icon?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @NickVu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this sandbox https://jsfiddle.net/w80qgdxe/

This is how I structured it. I don't have styled-component here, so I just use classes instead. You can convert them to styled-component in your code.

```css
.image {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto 3px auto 0; /* Aligned icon vertically */
}

.row {
  display: flex; /* Make row display */
  overflow: hidden; /* Make sure the content not going out of the box */
}

.content {
  margin: auto 0; /* Aligned content vertically */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keep content on the same line */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/1842/1842869.png" class="image" />
  <span class="content">Testing 123456</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This did fix the problem but not completely. Now I have overlap with the right column. It looks like https://i.imgur.com/EdaNz0U.png, notice the `timestamp` rows

Comment: Could you set `overflow: hidden;` on `.row`? By the way, I updated my answer too @anthino12